# flutter problem: How to make row and column like this and text position?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

Here I shared two screenshot, first one which I want like this and second one which i created.
I want horizontal vertical divider like in actual ui and text position too like in my actual ui.

this is my code.

```
import 'package:bonana_flutter/Constants/constants.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class details extends StatefulWidget {
  const details({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _detailsState createState() => _detailsState();
}

class _detailsState extends State<details> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: lightBlue,
      body: Container(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
SizedBox(height: 20,),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: Text(
                    "PAN Details Verified Successfully!",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: tSize32,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      color: greenColor,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 0.0, left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20),
                  child: Text(
                    "We have fetched these details from your pan card successfully.",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: tSize14,
                      color: greyColor,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 20.0, left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          Text("Name:"),
                          Text("Chetan Singh"),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Divider(),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          Text("PAN Number:"),
                          Text("XXXXXX0862"),
                        ],
                      ), Divider(),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          Text("Email Address:"),
                          Text("chitansingh1234@gmail.com"),
                        ],
                      ), Divider(),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          Text("Phone Number:"),
                          Text("XXXXXX1234"),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding:
                  const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, bottom: 20, left: 20, right: 20),
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 45,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          primary: skyBlue, shadowColor: Colors.transparent),
                      onPressed: () {
                      },
                      child: Text('Continue to Create MPIN',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: tSize16,
                          )),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),

    );
  }
}
```

I want like this ui.
[image]

this is my ui which I made.

[image]

Comment: @all thank you very much, all of you giving to me great suggetion, thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full code will be as this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Details(),
    );
  }
}

class Details extends StatefulWidget {
  const Details({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DetailsState createState() => _DetailsState();
}

class _DetailsState extends State<Details> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const borderSide = BorderSide(
      // define border to table
      width: 0.5, // define border to table
      color: Colors.grey, // define border to table
    ); // define border to table

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue[100],
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: Text(
                  "PAN Details Verified Successfully!",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 32,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    color: Colors.green,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 0.0, left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20),
                child: Text(
                  "We have fetched these details from your pan card successfully.",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 14,
                    color: Colors.grey[600],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 20.0, left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20),
                child: Table(
                  // use table with padding
                  columnWidths: const {
                    // use table columnWidths as you want
                    0: FlexColumnWidth(3), // use table columnWidths as you want
                    1: FlexColumnWidth(7), // use table columnWidths as you want
                  }, // use table columnWidths as you want
                  border: const TableBorder(
                      horizontalInside: borderSide,
                      verticalInside:
                          borderSide), // use border you defined before
                  children: <TableRow>[
                    // add table rows with style
                    TableRow(children: [
                      // add table rows with style
                      const Padding(
                        // add table rows with style
                        padding:
                            EdgeInsets.all(8.0), // add table rows with style
                        child: Text("Name:"), // add table rows with style
                      ), // add table rows with style
                      Padding(
                        // add table rows with style
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(
                            8.0), // add table rows with style
                        child: Text(
                          // add table rows with style
                          "Chetan Singh", // add table rows with style
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors
                                  .blue[800]), // add table rows with style
                        ), // add table rows with style
                      ), // add table rows with style
                    ]), // add table rows with style
                    TableRow(children: [
                      const Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Text("PAN Number:"),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Text(
                          "XXXXXX0862",
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue[800]),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ]),
                    TableRow(children: [
                      const Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Text("Email Address:"),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Text(
                          "chitansingh1234@gmail.com",
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue[800]),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ]),
                    TableRow(children: [
                      const Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Text("Phone Number:"),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Text(
                          "XXXXXX1234",
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue[800]),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ]),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 20.0, bottom: 20, left: 20, right: 20),
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: 45,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        primary: Colors.blue, shadowColor: Colors.transparent),
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: const Text('Continue to Create MPIN',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16,
                        )),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And the result of previous code:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can try this approach and does almost what you want:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
      body: Container(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                const SizedBox(height: 20,),
                const Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: Text(
                    "PAN Details Verified Successfully!",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      color: Colors.green,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 0.0, left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20),
                  child: Text(
                    "We have fetched these details from your pan card successfully.",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 14,
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 20.0, left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                              child: Text("Name:"),
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                border: Border(
                                  right: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 2)
                                ),
                              ),
                              width: 130,
                            height: 50,
                          ),
                          Text("Chetan Singh"),
                        ],
                      ),
                      const Divider(height: 0),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            child: Text("PAN Number:"),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              border: Border(
                                  right: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 2)
                              ),
                            ),
                            width: 130,
                            height: 50,
                          ),
                          Text("XXXXXX0862"),
                        ],
                      ), const Divider(height: 0),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            child: Text("Email Address:"),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              border: Border(
                                  right: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 2)
                              ),
                            ),
                            width: 130,
                            height: 50,
                          ),
                          Text("chitansingh1234@gmail.com"),
                        ],
                      ), const Divider(height: 0),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            child: Text("Phone Number:"),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              border: Border(
                                  right: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 2)
                              ),
                            ),
                            width: 130,
                            height: 50,
                          ),
                          Text("XXXXXX1234"),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding:
                  const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, bottom: 20, left: 20, right: 20),
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 45,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          primary: Colors.blue, shadowColor: Colors.transparent),
                      onPressed: () {
                      },
                      child: const Text('Continue to Create MPIN',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 16,
                          )),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),

    );
  }
```

[image: View1]

Answer (score 1):

i make the simple and short code for your output

**Output :-**

[image]

**Code :-**

make a list of values

```
List details = [
    {
      "title": "Name",
      "value": "Chetan Singh",
    },
    {
      "title": "PAN Number",
      "value": "XXXXXX0862",
    },
    {
      "title": "Email Address",
      "value": "chitansingh1234@gmail.com",
    },
    {
      "title": "Phone Number",
      "value": "XXXXXX1234",
    },
  ];
```

fetch details in listview

```
Column(
        children: List.generate(
          details.length,
          (index) => Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    width: size.width / 3,
                    child: Text("${details[index]["title"]}:"),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 44.0,
                    width: 0.5,
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0),
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                  Text(details[index]["value"]),
                ],
              ),
              Divider(
                thickness: 0.5,
                color: index == details.length - 1
                    ? Colors.transparent
                    : Colors.grey,
                height: 0.0,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Table](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Table-class.html) with

```
final borderSide = BorderSide(
    width: 1,
    color: Colors.grey,
  );

Table(
border: TableBorder(horizontalInside: borderSide, verticalInside: borderSide),
children: <TableRow>[...],
);
```